# Ordering Graylog search results

Tags: graylog2

Is there anyway to view search results in Graylog2 in chronological order?

The default seems to be to show them in reverse chronological order.

What I really want to do is find the first occurrence (in time) when a particular error happened. At the minute, the only way I can find to do this is select "all time" from the drop-down, and click 'next' page until I get to the last page of results.

Comment: Apparently sorting of result sets is supported in v0.20.0

Answer (score 2):

The currently released version of Graylog2 does unfortunately not support that. However v0.20.0 is being released really soon and will allow ordering search results.